# PropertyIndex.storeJSON("UserDB") in the same order of Properties or alphabetical order

Tags: codenameone

I have complex `PropertyBusinessObject`s with lots of Properties.
For my debugging/development purposes, it could be more convenient that the `storeJSON` method of the `PropertyIndex` saves the Properties inside the JSON in the same order that I've declared them in the `PropertyBusinessObject` or, if it's not possible, in alphabetical order.

Currently the Properties are stored in random order, that is fine for the code, but it's not fine for human reading.

How can I do that? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that but we can. I added a fix that will maintain the natural order of properties: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/a0a54c7d51ce980710eeecaf91ad4a1253c43e7f